# What do you call someone who likes variety?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't mean a variety in a certain field or area like food, but in general. I'm developing an iOS quiz app with different sections to be quizzed on. For example, there is a math quiz, a history quiz, a grammar quiz, a literature quiz, a history quiz, etc. One game center achievement is to have tried every quiz. I want the game center achievement title to be something like "diverse interests" except as a single word.

Comment: @JasperLoy see my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't really have enough context, but an [adventurous](http://www.ptypes.com/adventurous.html) [personality type] is one who displays *curiosity, interest, novelty-seeking, openness to experience.*

There's also [neophile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neophile) *(a personality type characterized by a strong affinity for novelty)*, but that's something of a "cult/jargon" neologism with rather more limited currency.

EDIT: Now the question has been edited to give more context, I suggest...

> [**intrepid**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intrepid) *(characterized by resolute fearlessness, fortitude, and **endurance**)*

...which seems to me a far more appropriate "honorific" for OP's category of game players.

EDIT2: [polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) *(a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas)*

Comment: For my purposes, "adventurous" is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider *[venturesome](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venturesome)* ("Bold; willing to take risks; adventurous"), *[mercurial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mercurial)* ("Volatile; erratic; unstable; flighty; [fickle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fickle) or changeable in temperament" or "Lively; clever; sprightly; animated; quick-witted"), *[impetuous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impetuous)* ("Making arbitrary decisions, especially in an impulsive and forceful manner") and some of their synonyms.

Note, with question as modified, perhaps only *venturesome* is relevant.  For titles of an achievement, consider *enthusiast*, *fanatic*, *experienced*, *well-rounded*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I almost picked "venturesome" but for some reason "adventurous" sounded more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't mind it being a word that's probably not immediately recognizable, you might consider **[philomath](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Philomath)**.  It means *lover of learning*, particularly in multiple disciplines.  Though rare, it seems apt for your purposes.

[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/philomath) describes it like this:

[image]

The award title might make people curious, and learn one more thing after they've won their award.

Comment: I dispute your *"particularly in multiple disciplines"*. You're conflating *philomath* with [polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, I considered both terms. (Maybe I should have mentioned them both for consideration.) Ultimately, I decided on _philomath_, based on the O.P.'s title of this question.  The question asked, "What do you call someone who loves **variety**?", put in the context of learning.  A _polymath_ has mastered many disciplines; a _philomath_ loves to learn. _Polymath_ seemed too pretentious for my tastes; no one becomes a da Vinci, Kepler, or Pascal by working thru a video game. I suppose I may have taken some artistic licence by adding a multidisciplinary aspect, but… -1? Ouch!

Comment: I don't dispute *philomath* as a credible answer (though I'd say if anything it's *more* "pretentious" than *polymath*, having [all but vanished](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polymath%2Cphilomath&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) over the past century. If the -1 hurts, and you've reconsidered, you can always edit out the phrase I dispute and I'll reverse my vote. The thing is, even though for others *philomath* probably implies nothing at all about *number of disciplines*, I associate it with ***one** discipline, pursued fanatically*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'll leave my answer as-is, and you can leave your downvote. It doesn't really sting _that_ much; as for "Ouch!" – I only had five characters left, so that's how I worded it. :^) Thanks for your comment; it prompted me to research more and think harder, which is the best part of frequenting EL&U. Who knows? Maybe this dialog down here might cause others to do the same.

Comment: haha - I'll probably end up doing my own research on this one, since I've admitted that quite possibly my own understanding of *philomath* is idiosyncratic (it's a word I'm barely familiar with anyway). But I absolutely agree that's one of the best things about ELU - you're often forced to re-evaluate something and accept that your own position isn't necessarily shared by everyone else. It's all grist to the mill though - what doesn't kill us makes us stronger, and language is a worthy discipline for the layman to dip into.